# Pascal - how can I return an array of a class from a function in that class?

Tags: arrays, function, class, return, pascal

If I have a class which has a protected property that's an array of that class and a public function to get that array and return it - how can I declare it so it allows the array as a return value?

Usually I'd use the

```
TNodeArray = array of Node
```

method but that can't work here. This is what I am trying:

```
Node = class
  protected
     Neighbours : array of Node;
  public
     function GetNeighbours() : array of Node; //This is the problem line
end;
```

Any help gratefully received! Thank you!

Comment: Apologies - just to clarify, the node would have other properties too. Thank you again

Comment: Replace the `array of Node`  declarations in the class with `TNodeArray`

Comment: @LURD- thank you! but if I have TNodeArray declared as array of Node - I can't link it can I? If I declare TNodeArray before the Node class then it won't initialise as it doesn't know what Node is yet. If I declare after the Node class then GetNeighbours()  : TNodeArray won't work as it won't know what TNodeArray is. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Yes, see my answer below how to forward declare the `Node` class in order to resolve the circular reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to use an array type as a parameter or a result value from a function is to use the distinct type declaration:

```
TNodeArray
```

Here you must also forward declare the `Node` class in order to resolve the circular reference.

```
Type

  Node = class;  // Forward declaration of the class

  TNodeArray = array of Node;

  Node = class
    protected
     Neighbours : TNodeArray;
    public
     function GetNeighbours() : TNodeArray; 
  end;
```